# Bitmaps and scaled bitmaps

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, scaling, recycle

I'm loading multiple bitmaps (aprox 40 of varying sizes from full-screen images to individual sprite frames) using:

```
Bitmap graphic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.mygraphics);
```

And then I am scaling them (so they will look the same size on any device relative to the screen) by using this:

```
Bitmap scaledGraphic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mygraphics,  screen.width()/2, screen.height()/2, true);
```

Above example is just for the sake of argument scaling the image up/down to a quarter of the screen size.

I then reference the scaled image in my onDraw() method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledGraphic, X, Y, null);
```

This all works OK and looks good on various screen sizes.

My question is, as I understand it, createScaledBitmap created another bitmap in memory from the original one (rather than just scaling the original one).  If this is the case, once the scaled bitmap has been created I really have no need for the original one any longer so is there any way I get rid of it from memory?

Would I need to call a recycle on it?  I'm just trying to optimize my code and have a lot of problems with stuttering animation etc... GC is getting called a few times (not a lot) and I really have no idea why this is happening but thought it would be good practice to sort this out anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think you should call `recycle()` on the original bitmap.

Comment: Thank you @LaiVung, I've added the recycling into my code :-)